# importerror: no module named bootstrap3_datetime

Tags: python, django

While runing "python manage.py migrate"
 i got error "importerror: no module named bootstrap3_datetime"

but in my pip freeze it is installed. 
django-bootstrap3==7.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a spelling mistake in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Check whether you have the right spelling for the name of the app.